# How to parse json when you have 'dynamic' values

Tags: python-3.x

Thanks for taking the time out to read this. I want to find a way of parsing the json below. I'm really struggling to get the correct values out. I am getting this info from an API, and want to save this data into a database.

I am really struggling to parse `info_per_type` because I first need to get the `available_types`. This can change depending on the info available (i.e. I might get 2 different types in the next call, there's a total of 4) so my code needs to be flexible enough to deal with this

````
``` 
{
    "data": [
        {
            "home_team": "Ravenna",
            "id": 82676,
            "available_types": [
                "type_a",
                "type_b"
            ],            
            "info_per_type": {
                "type_a": {
                    "options": {
                        "X": 0.302,
                        "X2": 0.61,
                        "X3": 0.692,
                        "X4": 0.698,
                        "X5": 0.39,
                        "X6": 0.308
                    },
                    "status": "pending",
                    "output": "12",
                    "option_values": {
                        "X": 3.026,
                        "X2": 1.347,
                        "X3": 1.516,
                        "X4": 1.316,
                        "X5": 2.936,
                        "X6": 2.339
                    }
                },
                "type_b": {
                    "options": {
                        "yes": 0.428,
                        "no": 0.572
                    },
                    "status": "pending",
                    "output": "no",
                    "option_values": {
                        "yes": null,
                        "no": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}```
````

So far, I can get the `available_types` out. But after that, I'm stuck. I have tried `eval` and `exec` but I can't seem to get that working either.

````
```
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    arrDetails = json.loads(r)
    arrDetails = arrDetails['data']
    x = arrDetails[0]['available_types']
    print(x[1]) #I get the correct value here
    y = exec("y = arrDetails[0]['info_per_type']['" + x[1] + "']")
    print(y)```
````

When I print out `y` I get `None`. What I want is some way to reference that part of the json file, as the results within that node are what I need. Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work :

```
for row in arrDetails['data']:
    for available_type in row['available_types']:
        print(row['info_per_type'][available_type])
```